# Passing values to arrays with draggable and droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need someone to help me with jQuery draggable and droppable.

1. Push/Pop values to Like/Hate Array when items drop and drag away.
2. When the items leave Like/Hate boxes, they can go back to where they come from, the correct div box.

I don't understand why when I drap/drop the boxes show me 2 names for a item, though now I can use $.unique() but it is not practice at all. And I have try many ways but not sure how to pop values out of Like/Hate Array when items are taken out.
Thank you very much!

[My code is here](https://jsfiddle.net/yy2412kimo/ohk7cq9h/)

```
  Like = [];
  Hate = [];
$(function () {
    $("#AllTable .test").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
    });

    $(".LikeBox div").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var $item = ui.draggable;
            $item.appendTo("#likeTable");
            var ingre = $item.text();

            alert(ingre);
            Like.push(ingre);
            Like = $.unique(Like)
        }
    });

    $(".HateBox div").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var $item = ui.draggable;
            $item.appendTo("#hateTable");

            var ingre = $item.text();
            Hate.push(ingre);
            Hate = $.unique(Hate)
        }
    });

    $(function () {
        $('.IngreMainCat').accordion();
    });
});
```

**Edit:**
My new code is this, problem 1 solved:

```
Like = [];
Hate = [];

$(function() {
  $( "#AllTable .test" ).draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
  });

  $( ".LikeBox .droptrue" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var $item = ui.draggable;
      $item.appendTo("#likeTable");
      var ingre = $item.text();
      Like.push(ingre);
      if($.inArray(ingre,Hate) > -1){
        var index = Hate.indexOf(ingre);
        if (index > -1) {
          Hate.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    } 
  }); 

  $( ".HateBox .droptrue" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var $item = ui.draggable;
      $item.appendTo("#hateTable");
      var ingre = $item.text();
      Hate.push(ingre);
      if($.inArray(ingre,Like) > -1){
        var index = Like.indexOf(ingre);
        if (index > -1) {
          Like.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    } 
  });

});
```

Comment: I'm assuming it gets triggered onReceive and onDragEnd.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

You actually have 2 divs that are droppable because of your selector. Since you call all child divs of `.LikeBox` you get these 2 droppables that each run the drop function:

```
  <div>
  <div id="likeTable" class="droptrue">
```

After droppable is called it looks like this, see `ui-droppable` on both:

```
<div class="ui-droppable">
      <div id="likeTable" class="droptrue ui-droppable">
```

Clarify your selector and you shouldn't have the problem. Like this for example:

```
$( ".LikeBox .droptrue" ).droppable({
```

see working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ets9hjg/

EDIT:

For the elements to remove from your arrays, a suggestion: instead of using `push` and `pop` and keep track of what you add and remove in the tables, you can `map` you tables when you need them. See jquery map: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/. It's easier to keep track that way. Like this:

```
Like = $.map($( "#likeTable div" ),function(a){return a.textContent});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2ets9hjg/4/

Comment: Thank you soooo much Julien, this helps a lot! I now solved problem 1!

Comment: Thanks Julien so much for your help again! However, I think in this way, another Array would still have incorrect item stay inside.. I have updated my code. Thanks again!

Comment: It depends when you call the map function. If you keep it in the drop event, indeed it'll keep unwanted items. But the idea is to call it when you need the arrays. The thing is your likeTables behave a bit like arrays of divs, so there's no reason to keep separate arrays in sync. Simply, when you need to display or access content, you check what's in your likeTables using map function and you'll always have updated content. See example with a button showing content of arrays: https://jsfiddle.net/2ets9hjg/7/